# sort letters in a single word - use it to find permutations (or anagrams)

Tags: sort, words

I have some dictionary to myspell in `file.dic`. Let's say:

```
abc
aword
bword
cab
worda
wordzzz
```

and I'm looking for different words that are **permutations (or anagrams)** of each other.

If there was a command "letter-sort" I'd do it more or less like that:

```
cat file.dic | letter-sort | paste - file.dic | sort
```

That gives me:

```
abc abc
abc cab
adorw aword
adorw worda
bdorw bword    
dorwzzz wordzzz
```

so now I clearly see anagrams in file. Is there such `letters-sort` command or how to obtain such result in maybe some other way?

Comment: How does `worda` become `aword`?

Comment: Thanks @pfnuesel. Fixed now :) My fault, should be `adorw` - assuming order like in alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort letters line by line in a file, you could do something like that:

```
while read line; do
    grep -o . <<< "${line}" | sort | tr -d '\n'
    echo
done < file.dic
```

Output:

```
abc
adorw
bdorw
abc
adorw
dorwzzz
```

Comment: It works, but it's very sloooow :) For dictionary of ~300k words (lines) it took several minutes. I'll try to use pipes with python scritpt later on to make it faster.

Comment: I can imagine this is slow. For a faster solution, you should try python or perl.

Comment: Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: @pfnuesel, please add a note to your answer about the slowness.  This is very bad practice; at the least you should put a warning flag at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fold` command to break a string into an array of individual characters, like the script below

```
#!/bin/bash

CHARS=`echo $1 | fold -w1`
# $CHARS now contain an array of single character in the string $1

for i in "${CHARS[@]}"
do
    # do something with each character
    echo $i;
done
```

Assuming that you have saved the script above as `test.sh` you can run it as follows:

```
$./test.sh abcde
```

and it will break the string "abcde" into a characters array, which then you can use to find its anagrams.

Comment: I've tested it and `fold` is much faster than `grep`, unfortunately, it doesn't work in non-latin locale.

Comment: Hmmmm..... it works for me (just tested with greek input)
    $ echo δοκιμή | fold -w1
    δ
    ο
    κ
    ι
    μ
    ή

Comment: Doesnt work with Polish though :/ `echo "zażółć gęślą jaźń" | fold -w1` at least on my system.

Comment: Indeed! And I just figured out why: It seems that if all characters in the string are unicode non-ascii (like the greek) it correctly uses two bytes for each character (unicode representation). In the case of polish it fails to do so, as it interpret correctly each character's length (either one or two) and interprets everything as one byte character. Same happens if I mix greek with english like  this `echo δοκιμή test | fold -w1
` :\

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned `python`, just stick with `python`. Two words are anagrams of each other if 1. they contain the same letters and 2. letter frequencies match. The built-in `Counter` class can be used to do one-pass letter frequencies without the need for sorting

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
with open('file') as f:
    data = (l.rstrip('\n') for l in f)
    data = ((l, Counter(l)) for l in data)
    perms = defaultdict(list)
    for l, c in data:
        perms[frozenset(c.iteritems())].append(l)   
    for anagrams in perms.itervalues():
        print(*anagrams)

bword
aword worda
abc cab
wordzzz
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl with it's command line flags can be very good at being succinct:

The following command sorts letters in a word

```
perl -CS -ne 'chomp; print(join("", sort(split("", $_ . "\n"))))'
```

In practice, if you are working with anagrams you might prefer to use the `an` utility. This can take a dictionary as an argument:

```
an -d /usr/share/dict/ngerman Anagramword
```